# Finding index of x numbers in list that add up to target (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to find the indices of x numbers in a list that add up to a specific target.

When I input the following code in python, no output is given.

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Matteo

---

```
import random
import math

def find(number):
    final = []
    trans = random.sample(values,number)
    summation = sum(trans)
    number_of_guesses = 0
    while number_of_guesses < math.factorial(len(values))/math.factorial(len(values)- 
    number):
        if summation == target:
            for i in range(len(values)):
                if trans[i] in values:
                    final.append(i)
                    return final
                else:
                    trans = random.sample(values,number)
                    find(number)
            number_of_guesses += 1

values = [100, 150, 140, 100, 120, 270, 500, -100, 120, 150, 160]
target = 390
find(2)
```

Comment: When you recurse with `find(number)` you don't `return`. I suspect you wanted `return find(number)` - but I question combining recursion and iteration. This approach seems specious. For example, if `summation` is not `target` you just continue to loop forever.

Comment: thanks @ElliottFrisch. So I would just need to adjust 'find(number)' to 'return find(number)'? I understand your point though - my computer is struggling to find the solution haha. I'll need to find a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an approach using recursion, where `find_ind()` is what you want.

```py
def find_val(num, target, values):
    if num == 1 or values == []:
        return [target] if target in values else []
    x, subvalues = values[0], values[1:]
    if subfound := find_val(num - 1, target - x, subvalues):
        return [x] + subfound
    else:
        return find_val(num, target, subvalues)

def find_ind(num, target, values, offset=0):
    if num == 1 or values == []:
        return [offset + values.index(target)] if target in values else []
    x, subvalues = values[0], values[1:]
    if subfound := find_ind(num - 1, target - x, subvalues, offset + 1):
        return [offset] + subfound
    else:
        return find_ind(num, target, subvalues, offset + 1)

values = [100, 150, 140, 100, 120, 270, 500, -100, 120, 150, 160]
target = 390

print(find_val(3, target, values)) # [100, 150, 140]
print(find_ind(3, target, values)) # [0, 1, 2]

print(find_val(11, 1710, values)) # [100, 150, 140, 100, 120, 270, 500, -100, 120, 150, 160]
print(find_ind(11, 1710, values)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I'll explain `find_val()` as it is somewhat easier to explain. Given a list `values` of values, it first picks the first element `x`. Now it asks itself (recursion) whether it can find `num - 1` numbers from the sublist `values[1:]` that sum to `target - x`.

If those numbers exist, then this recursion would have returned those numbers. Otherwise, `[]` would have been returned. (Or, you promise yourself to implement this sort of returns.)

If the former is the case, it means that `x` and those returned numbers would sum to `target`. So return `[x] + "return from recursion"`.

If the latter is the case (i.e., the sublist cannot make `target - x`), then `x` cannot find its friends to make `target`. But don't return `[]` yet; we have not considered items other than this first one. So now recurse with the same `num` and same `target` but with a sublist `values[1:]`. This recursion will end when there is no first item to be called `x`; i.e., when `values == []`.

`find_ind()` follows the same argument, but with an extra parameter `offset`. This keeps track of where the given list starts in the original list.

Comment: Thanks a lot @j1-lee for the thorough feedback - it's highly appreciated!